# Push notifications only work when the app is running

Tags: android, push-notification, trigger.io

Created an app with Trigger.io and the parse module to include push notifications. Installed the app on Android devices (2.3 and 4).

If a notification is sent when the app isn't running - it won't notify the user. Only when I launch the app the notification I sent before is received.
If a notification is sent when the app is running in the background, it will be received.

This is how I subscribe:

```
forge.partners.parse.push.subscribe("channel", onSuccess, onFail);
```

This is how I listen to a message:

```
forge.event.messagePushed.addListener(messagePushed);
```

### Edit

Created public minimalist test application that reproduces this behavior. Your can find it here: https://github.com/rotev/trigger_io_push_notifications_test
Note that I removed local_config.json, identity.json and config.json from the source because it contains sensitive information.

Your help would be greatly appriciated :\

Answer (score 2):

When you enable Parse in a Trigger app the app includes a background service to receive pushes from Parse and display them. There are a few reasons why this service might not be running:

- If you force close the application then this service will be stopped temporarily.
- If you have any apps on your device which "save memory" by killing background services
- If your device is running low on memory it may kill the service until more memory is available.

You should be able to see if the service is running from the running apps tab in the device settings. If is it not running then one of the above reasons might have killed it, if it is running and you still aren't seeing the notifications then there may be another issue.

It is also worth considering that notifications from Parse can sometimes be slightly delayed.

Comment: Thanks! I tested this behavior on Facebook's messenger application. I shut it down through my phone's task manager and sent myself a message through another user, but it did notify me about it.